# Sugar ORM No such table exception

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Sugar ORM works perfectly on Android <5, but on Android 5> it crashes.
I am using version 1.4

Please help me.

Error: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: AUDIO (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM AUDIO`

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models.** { *; }
```

My model class:

```
package me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Audio extends SugarRecord {
    private long aud_id;
    private String aud_artist;
    private String aud_title;
    private String aud_url;
    private long aud_duration;

    public Audio() {
    }

    public Audio(long aud_id, String aud_artist, String aud_title, String aud_url, long aud_duration){
        this.aud_id = aud_id;
        this.aud_artist = aud_artist;
        this.aud_title = aud_title;
        this.aud_url = aud_url;
        this.aud_duration = aud_duration;
    }
}
```

My application class:

```
public class App extends SugarApp {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="mp3downloadsfree.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="5" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="me.lobanov.mp3downloadsfree.models" />
```

Comment: did you find a solution?
i had been using sugar for some time now and it just started giving this error, everything seems fine, all configurations are correct, every sugar class has public default constructor

Comment: I write my own class without sugar orm

Comment: if you have recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 then the Instant Run feature causes problems with the SQL table creation which will lead on to the exception you are having. Disable Instant run to fix

Comment: @DeanWild bro, thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disabling instant run worked for me.

Comment: @snehasish go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

Comment: I must add that you may re-enable Instant Run after the first install of the app with it disabled.

Answer (score 3):

If you already ran your app with sugar and then later you added a model that gives the 'no such table error', then you need to just update(increase) your database VERSION meta in your AndroidManifest.xml. This solves the problem most of the time when instant run is not the issue. Look at the issue [HERE](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/628)
For more  insight.

Answer (score 1):

And after you disable instant run, make sure you uninstall the app from the phone/emulator before running again.

Answer (score 1):

I was using version 1.3 and faced same problem.
But I solved by using gradle version 1.5 and initializing SugarContext.

In gradle dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
```

In onCreate Method:

```
 SugarContext.init(this);
```

Comment: Disabling *instant run* may help.

Answer (score 0):

please implement hack findById function on your onCreate application class like this

```
public class App extends SugarApp {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Audio.findById(Audio.class, (long) 1);
    }
}
```

Your audio table will be created

Answer (score 0):

The message java.lang.NoSuchTable: means that someone tried to call a constructor without any parameters. Adding a default constructor should solve this problem:

```
public class User 
{
    public User() {
    }
    ..
}
```