# No such table Sugar ORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm having a lot of problems with Sugar ORM in my Android project.

That is the error:

```
    05-07 18:50:42.173 7252-7252/net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters, PID: 7252
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters/net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters.addPlan}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PLAN (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO PLAN(ID,NAME) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PLAN (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO PLAN(ID,NAME) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:280)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:416)
        at net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters.addPlan.onCreate(addPlan.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And my entity class is that:

```
    package net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;
import com.orm.dsl.Unique;

/**
 * Created by sergio on 7/05/16.
 */

public class Plan extends SugarRecord {
    @Unique
    String name;


    // Default constructor is necessary for SugarRecord
    public Plan() {

    }

    public Plan(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem happen when I try to do the next code:

```
package net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

public class addPlan extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_plan);

        Plan plan = new Plan("Plan1");
        plan.save();

        List<Plan> plans = Plan.listAll(Plan.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < plans.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Plan: " + plans.get(i).getName());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Please I need help, I disabled the option Instant run like in every posts said but it doesnt work.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBlY1.png)

Thanks for your help.

My android manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="example.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="net.elinformaticoenganchado.sergio.crossfighters" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".chronometer" />
        <activity android:name=".addPlan" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you configure your application correctly? As in, you need to define a `SugarApp` class and set it up in the manifest?  http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I have configure correctly.

Comment: try this anwser......... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792152/sugar-orm-no-such-table-exeption

Comment: @ExceptionLover Like I told you i tried to disabling instant run and it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved by creating an empty "migration script file with new version". 
This can be simply done by following :

1. Create your new Sugar record class.
2. In Android manifest file just increase the DB version.

By doing this, it creates the new table without dropping/creating my old tables.

My version is 1.5

Comment: I had the same issue. I was using sugar-orm in version 1.4. At the beginning with **Instant Run** enabled I received **SQLiteException**. After disabling this option and incrementing **VERSION** in manifest everything ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a db modification you have to remove the app and install as a fresh app or change the db version and write an alter query.